# Is there a pure Scala equivalent of Apache Commons beanutils

Tags: scala

Is there a pure Scala equivalent of Apache Commons BeanUtils.cloneBean ?

I could use beanutils, but have to add @scala.reflect.BeanInfo to my scala classes.

Given a class A and a class B, I need a way to copy all the fields from an object of class A to create a new object of class B only copying the fields which exist in Class A and class B having the same name and type.

The reason for doing this is I'm reading data from a MongoDB database using the excellent casbah and Salat, transforming the data into something broadly similar and writing to a new MongoDB database. So for the fields which are common, I just want to copy all the common fields in 1 line, without having to write code for each field, then transform the fields which differ.

Perhaps copying each field manually is the correct way, as it is explicit about what I am copying. I could pass the values to the constructor of class B.

Comment: What if Class B requires more fields than what Class A provides in order to be complete? Bean-style classes are imho not good Scala style, because beans rely on using `null`.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your comments. Yes, I sort of sensed beanutils was not idiomatic Scala, hence my question. If class B requires more fields, than I could make use of a mutable object, but I'm thinking more and more that when I come to implement this anytime now, I will manually transpose each field from class A to class B making use of a Case Class constructor. Some fields will be literal copies, other will split into multiple fields, others will be computed or be sourced from data sources.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the simple approach of translating each field from class A to class B, transforming and adding any new fields required by class B where needed. Works for me.